# How to export Plotly plot in .html format from tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, plotly

I want to process the data and export the results as a html graph using the tkinter application. but an empty file appears at the specified location on the computer.

```
def but1():
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    file = fd.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".html",
                            filetypes=(("HTML file", "*.html"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    if file:
        file.write(py.plot(fig))
        file.close()


root = Tk()
but0 = Button(root, text="(●'◡'●)", command=but0, height=2, width=10)
but1 = Button(root, text="¯\_(ツ)_/¯", command=but1, height=2, width=10)
label = Label(root, text="выбери файл")
label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
but0.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
but1.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)
root.geometry("150x120")
root.mainloop()
```

I want the html file to be saved in the selected location

Comment: Can you use `plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='name.html')`?

Comment: yes, i tried this, but it saves .html plot in project directory, and when i save my cod to .exe file it do anything at all

Comment: if you use a `filename` that is a full filepath, it should save to wherever you point it. Are you on mac, linux, or windows?

Comment: @MasonCaiby windows10

Comment: Can you try saving it to: `C:\Users\` + your username+ `\Desktop\filename`. It should save to your desktop

Comment: @MasonCaiby 
`import plotly.offline as py
def but1():
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    file = fd.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".html",
                            filetypes=(("HTML file", "*.html"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    if file:
        file.write(py.plot(fig, filename='C:\Users\dima\Desktop\primer.html'))
        file.close()`
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: How can you run python in a .exe file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your function to this:

```
import plotly.offline as py 
def but1_function(): 
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout) 
    py.plot(fig, filename='C:\Usersdima\Desktop\primer.html', auto_open=False)

but1 = Button(root, text="¯\_(ツ)_/¯", command=but1_function, height=2, width=10)
```

Also, you have `but1` defined as a function and as a button; so you'll overwrite the function when you make `but1 = Button(root, text="¯\_(ツ)_/¯", command=but1_function, height=2, width=10)` so I changed the name of the function.

Comment: thank you soooo much, i tried to do it for week by myself

Comment: You can also make it so `but1_function()` accepts a variable file name, e.g.: `def but1_function(target_file):` then save to that variable: `py.plot(fig, filename=target_file, auto_open=False)`

Comment: `def but1_function():
    file = fd.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".html",
                            filetypes=(("HTML file", "*.html"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    py.plot(fig, filename=file.name, auto_open=False)`
that's how i do it, thank you one more time

Comment: but it still don't work after i save my app in .exe file with pyinstaller. app just save empty .html file((

Comment: try `print()`ing the contents of the file to the terminal you're running the `.exe` from. Trouble shooting exe's can be really difficult because they don't show their error. you can print the plot with: `print(plotly.offline.plot(fig))` just before the line that saves the html to a file.

Comment: print write default file name 'temp-plot.html'